# Oscillator Barkhausen condition

Tags: oscillator

[image: simple ring oscillator]

I am wondering whether this simple ring oscillator is in positive or negative feedback. As per general oscillator operation it should be either positive feedback or 180 phase shift but what I see from the image 1 is connected in negative feedback using simple analysis. Can anyone explain how intuitively it became positive feedback?

[image]

Comment: *I am wondering whether this simple oscillator is in positive or negative feedback.* <--An oscillator is always using positive feedback. Your images don't provide enough information to  decide whether it oscillates though.

Comment: @Andyaka I disagree.180 degrees phase inversion is negative feedback by definition

Comment: Miss Mulan I think you're right about the definition, but there's a 360 degree phase shift here - from a gate and back to the same gate it's 360 degrees, in three sections of 120 degrees.

Comment: @Andyaka it’s simple ring oscillator structure

Comment: I know what it is but there's a lack of information is what I said.

Answer (score 2):

Each working oscillator needs

(a) negative feeedback for DC (stable DC operating point), and

(b) positive feedback for a single frequency, in particular: Loop gain with zero deg. phase shift and a gain value above unity (preferrable only slightly >1).

Both requirements are fulfilled for the shown circuit. Three RC-blocks provide at a single frequency a phase shift of -180deg. That means: Together with three phase inversions (common source stages) this results in a total phase of -360deg=0 deg.

Answer (score 1):

Each FET inverts the signal which is usually interpreted as a \$180^\circ\$ phase shift. Each FET has a small delay which translates to a small negative phase shift ( pretend it is \$-2^\circ\$). Then the RC network provides a phase lag, which at the oscillation frequency will settle to \$-58^\circ\$. The combined phase shift is:
$$180^\circ-2^\circ-58^\circ=120^\circ$$
per section.

So for three sections you will have \$360^\circ\$ phase shift which is positive feedback.

Answer (score 0):

At a certain frequency, each RC section produces a phase shift of 60°. Consequently, a complete phase shift of 180° is created with the RC sections. This makes the feedback positive at this frequency.

Just one example of oscillation:
[image]

Comment: "*at this frequency*" -- what frequency is that? I don't see a number, anywhere. Not even a mention of frequency (other than yours).

Comment: Yes that's true. However, this structure can be an oscillator with the same RC elements and FETs. Without specific values, only in general.

Answer (score 0):

In implementations with only a single MOSFET, it's easier to see: the input voltage, let's say 0 phase, gets shifted 180 degrees by the transistor and another 180 degrees by the RC network to a total of 360 degrees.

Here I suspect that you'd find a 360 degree shift looking from the gate of either of the three MOSFETs and back to the same gate.

Since it's a capacitative load and not purely resistive, each MOSFET can cause a 120 degree shift (rather than 180) at a certain frequency.

At that frequency if the gate of M3 is at phase 0, the gate of M1 is at 120, and the gate of M2 is at 240, such that it's back to zero at the gate of M3.

Since what returns to the gate of M3 does not work to reduce the voltage there, but perpetuates it, it's positive feedback.

I believe the issue you might be concerned about is that each MOSFET would appear to be shifting by 180 degrees, and so what comes back to M3 should be 180 degree phase shifted from what had left it.

This is not the case because the capacitors make the phase shift 120 at each section (at the oscillation frequency.)

If the circuit didn't have capacitors, or the capacitors were so big that they had virtually caused no phase shift, all the circuit could have done in that case is return a 180 degree inverted input back to M3, like you suggested. In this case, the feedback would indeed be negative as you suggested, but then the circuit would simply not develop an oscillation on top of its steady DC biasing.

Note that sinusoidal oscillation is on top of the DC steady state rather than instead of it. Some noise in one of the capacitors on top of the steady state voltage builds up to an oscillation, if at the beginning the return voltage is greater than the input voltage. Ultimately to maintain a sine wave and not send the transistors to saturation or cutoff, the Barkhaussen criteria value is just 1, and then an oscillation amplitude is maintained.

Square wave vibrators, not the case here, work on a different principle - no steady state is stable so they "try" one with some transistors cutoff & others saturated. When the capacitors charge enough to make that state impossible, the system flips, with the cutoff transistors activating and the saturated ones cutting off, until the capacitors charge or discharge enough to make that state impossible also. At that point the transistors assume the state they've had earlier, and so on in a repeating cycle, between two transistor
states (unfortunately books usually don't keep a distinction between the two types of oscillators, sinusoidal and square, even as the principle of operation is different).

I believe also that you might not want to attach the feedback path to ground like in your second image, unless you use something like a million ohm resistor and then it's effectively an open circuit.

Comment: I suppose, the last circuit is intended to show how the loop gain is determined (simulated). In principle, this is a good method to verify if the oscillation condition is fulfilled - or not. However, in the shown figure, the whole circuit has no DC bias - it will not work. Therefore, it is better to place the test voltage (for finding the loop gain) BETWEEN both ends of the opening. Then, the loop gain is nothing else than the voltage ratio at both ends.

Comment: Hmm, because there's a DC voltage to each gate, and above each drain. (Capacitors open circuits under it). And on top of this DC state, oscillation can develop. The answer below mine shows this with a 15V source. Probably a 9V source would have been sufficient as well.